# Finagle filter sequence of futures of option

Tags: scala, finagle, twitter-finagle

I am using `twitter finagle` framework and given a sequence of future of optionals I would like to filter them based on the state of the option.

```
seqFuture : Seq[Future[Option[Foo]]] 
val filteredFuture = seqFuture map { fut => fut map {
      opt => if(opt.isDefined) bar(opt.get)
   }
}
```

The function `bar : Foo => Bar` could be identity, but I do not want to return an `Option[Bar]`. If the option is not defined I want the future to silently fail and only chain further processing on the futures that contain a defined option.

I have tried a combination of `flatten, flatMap, match case Some(_) =>`, but I do not arrive at filtering them. If I throw an `Exception` where the option is not defined all of the futures processing will fail (since I collect them at some point)

I could not find any solution to this problem in [finagle guide](https://twitter.github.io/finagle/guide)

Alternative solutions to filter and chaining futures using the finagle framework would still be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with the two layers of `map` here (first the `Seq`, then the `Future`) is that this approach doesn't allow you to "skip" the futures that compute empty options.

If you use `Future.collect` (note that the standard library and other APIs call this operation `sequence`), you can do this as a one-liner, and also end up with a `Future[Seq[...]]`, which is almost always a nicer thing to have than a `Seq[Future[...]]`:

```
def filteredFuture: Future[Seq[Foo]] = Future.collect(seqFuture).map(_.flatten)
```

If you *really* need to go from a `Seq[Future[Option[Foo]]]` to a `Seq[Future[Foo]]` (instead of the `Future[Seq[Foo]]` you get from `collect`), you're kind of out of luck. You could do it if you're willing to have any `None` values result in failed futures, but these will blow up when you call something like `collect` down the line, and if you want them to be silently ignored, you'll have to handle those failures explicitly. I'd strongly suggest using `Future.collect` and going directly to the `Future[Seq[Foo]]`.